# TextView Content Lost on Screen Lock

Tags: android, textview, persist

I have a TextView with a user name inside that , but when the device screen locks(On,Off) , the text inside that will be gone .i have tried adding `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` to ManifestFile and also use `android:freezesText="true"` for the TextView , both with no success .

i've also used :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putString("userName", username);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    String userName = savedInstanceState.getString("userName");
    TextView viewName = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.username);
    viewName.setText(userName);
}
```

but onRestoreInstanceState doesn't fire on device screen lock!
does anybody know why this happens and how can i prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <TextView 
         ... 
         android:freezesText="true" />

//or n order to retain data on orientation change you need to implement the two methods:

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Read values from the "savedInstanceState"-object and put them in your textview
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Save the values you need from your textview into "outState"-object
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```